# Consolidate the duplicate templates into a single template with some sort of selector or perhaps a variable

Tags: templates, xslt

How do I turn the four nearly identical templates in to one? I would like to be able to have a variable or at least a single place where I can specify the group of parent nodes?

I've attempted to something like

```
<xsl:template match="ViewSuperbillProcedureScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillProcedureScrub|ViewSuperbillScrub/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="*[ViewSuperbillProcedureScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillProcedureScrub|ViewSuperbillScrub]/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
```

or

```
<xsl:varname name="NodeList">ViewSuperbillProcedureScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillScrubFullInsurance|ViewSuperbillProcedureScrub|ViewSuperbillScrub</xsl:varname>
<xsl:template match="$NodeList/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
```

but nothing works.

Here's the full xsl:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ViewSuperbillProcedureScrubFullInsurance/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:attribute name="AutoWidth">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ViewSuperbillScrubFullInsurance/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:attribute name="AutoWidth">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ViewSuperbillProcedureScrub/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:attribute name="AutoWidth">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ViewSuperbillScrub/column/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:attribute name="AutoWidth">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do:

```
<xsl:template match="column[parent::ViewSuperbillScrub or parent::ViewSuperbillProcedureScrub or parent::ViewSuperbillScrubFullInsurance or parent::ViewSuperbillProcedureScrubFullInsurance]/@width[not(../@AutoWidth)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:attribute name="AutoWidth">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But that only makes sense if your input also has another `column` with a `width` attribute but a different parent:

```
//SomeOtherNode/column/@width
```

that should **not** be processed the same way.